# Слишком много знаков в символьной константе

Tags: c++, типы-данных

Пишу программу для декодирования текста на С++, ниже приведен пример. char не может обработать больше четырех знаков, что можно сделать, или как можно изменить тип данных для корректной обработки кода?

```
string letterToDigits(const string& s)
{

    static unordered_map<char, string>m{ {'0000001',"а"},{'00000001',"б"} };
    string str{};

    for_each(s.cbegin(), s.cend(), [&str](const char& c)noexcept {

        auto f = m.find(c);

        str += (f != m.end()) ? f->second : "";

        });

    return str;

}
```

Comment: А что вы понимаете под `'0000001'`? Что это за ***символ***?

Comment: Кодирование методом Шеннона-Фано, кодирование производилось вручную, программа нужна, чтобы закодировать сообщение по принципу "буква = последовательность чисел", проблема в переводе обратно "последовательность чисел = буква", в примере подразумевается замена '0000001' на символ "а".

Comment: Еще раз и медленно. Например, `'a'` — это символ *a*. ОДИН символ. Как может ваш  символ (`char`) состоять из восьми символов? Как вы "*последовательность чисел*" хотите запихнуть в один символ?

Comment: В изначальном алфавите 32 буквы, соответственно, буквы, которые используются реже, кодируются не одним символом. В примере я привел часть кода, чтобы не писать всю простыню замен. Изначальная замена производилась по принципу {'а',"0000001"}, то есть буква а менялась на соответствующий ей код, сейчас я пытаюсь произвести замену обратно, чтобы программа в строке при появлении этой последовательности меняла ее на букву а.

Comment: char не может обработать более одного знака ASCII. Используйте строки.

Comment: Можете подсказать конструкцию, как их использовать? Насколько я понимаю, string является классом для работы со строками, и я не понимаю как этот код можно изменить для корректного использования.

Comment: Что мешает сделать `unordered_map<string, string>m = { {"\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01","а"}, ...  };`? Вы можете заполнить строку любыми символами, используя их шестнадцатиричные коды

Comment: Стандартная мапа вам не поможет. Нужно делать свое двоичное дерево, со строками в листьях.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Литерал вида `'...'` имеет тип `char`, а вы пытаетесь поместить в него строку `0000001`, что есть массив `char`. Для строковых литералов используется `"..."`, поэтому замена `'0000001'` на `"0000001"` + изменение типа с `char` на `std::string` должны помочь.